# How to create a email with a large attachment in a shared mailbox

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-mail

I can not upload large (more than 4Mb) attachment to an email created in a shared mailbox using Microsoft Graph. The steps that I followed are [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-large-attachments) but they did not work.

Creating draft (OK):

```
=> POST /users/sharedmailbox@account.onmicrosoft.com/mailFolders('drafts')/messages

{ message json }

<= 201

{ message json, id:"XXXX" }
```

Uploading small attachment (OK):

```
=> POST /users/sharedmailbox@account.onmicrosoft.com/messages/XXXX/attachments

{"contentBytes": "BASE64..." }

<= 201 

{ attachment json }
```

Uploading large attachment (FAIL)

```
=> POST
/users/sharedmailbox@account.onmicrosoft.com/messages/XXXX/attachments/createUploadSession

{ AttachmentItem: { attachment json } }

<= 201 

{ upload session json, uploadUrl: "https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/Users('guid@otherguid')/Messages('XXXX')?authtoken=SOME-JWT" }
```

```
=> PUT uploadUrl-from-above

attachment-body

<= 403 

{ 
  "error": {
    "code":"ErrorAccessDenied",
    "message":"Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."
  }
}
```

I have requested the following permissions: `user.read`, `mail.readwrite`, `mail.send`, `mail.readwrite.shared`, `mail.send.shared`. And an email with a small attachment is perfectly created in a shared mailbox.

How can I create an email with a large attachment in a shared mailbox via Microsoft Graph?

Answer (score 1):

The [`createUploadSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-beta#permissions) endpoint requires one of the following permission scopes: `Files.ReadWrite`, `Files.ReadWrite.All`, `Sites.ReadWrite.All`.

Since this involves another user, I believe you'll need `Files.ReadWrite.All` since `Files.ReadWrite` only provides access to your own Drive.

Comment: Good idea, thanks, but it did not help. Using an access token with these extra permissions produces the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is now listed as [known issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#attaching-large-files-to-messages) at the ms docs site.